# How to execute code when a DependencyProperty is first read?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create something like late binding for a `DependencyProperty`.
I have a `ListView` with icons. I want icons loaded only when they are actually needed / displayed. When the icon elements are displayed, `GetValue` on `IconProperty` is called, but it only can return default value (which is `null`). I want to inject code to load relevant icon when initial value is `null`.

My first approach was creating custom getter / setter for the property without using `DependencyProperty` at all. It works, however I wonder if it's optimal.

When I use `DependencyProperty` I can easily determine when it's changed via `OnPropertyChanged` override. I have no idea when should I inject initialization for getter.

```
public class DisplayItem : DependencyObject {

    // ...

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Icon",
            typeof(ImageSource),
            typeof(DisplayItem),
            null
        );

    public ImageSource Icon {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(IconProperty); }
        private set { SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
    }

    private void GetIcon() {
        // Some code to actually fetch the icon image...
        // ...
        Icon = loadedImageSource;
    }

    // ...

}
```

Consider the code above: how to call `GetIcon()` exactly before first `GetValue()` occurs?

Comment: You can use [async binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.isasync(v=vs.110).aspx) to cache icon when it's requested for the first time. Consider to use MVVM, you don't need dependency property, but a simple one with notification (`INotifyPropertyChanged`). Item view model (collection of which is bound to `ListView.ItemsSource`) can hold Icon.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning async binding, it seems like the right choice for icons, anyway I implemented MVVM here, it's probably better choice considering my `DisplayItem` belongs to `ObservableCollection` used by an `ItemSource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use a dependency property.

A plain CLR property (with an optional `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation) is sufficient:

```
public class DisplayItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ImageSource icon;

    public ImageSource Icon
    {
        get
        {
            if (icon == null)
            {
                icon = ... // load here
            }
            return icon;
        }
        private set
        {
            icon = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Icon"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need `DependencyObject` for other two-way bindings (item `CheckBox` affects column `CheckBox`), but I can have both, so I just changed icon property to plain and this is it. Thanks.

Comment: Note that DisplayItem does not need to be a DependencyObject as long as its properties are the source of a binding, even when the binding is two-way. In general, a view model class should never be a DependencyObject.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I converted my class to correct view model. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to know when the dependency property value is being accessed? 
If bound to some property in the view, the property will be accessed on initially loading the components. Hence, you can call that `GetIcon()` when on `Loaded`. If you’re using MVVM, just bind the Loaded event to some command, else simply handle the event and call the function.

If you’re planning to move to MVVM pattern, just using a CLR property as the other answer suggests, would do the trick.

Comment: It seems like MVVM is the right choice here. I knew I was doing something wrong :) But according to MSDN: "View models satisfy this requirement by implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and raising the PropertyChanged event when a property is changed." - so I should use CLR property in MVVM anyway.

Comment: **Yes. Exactly.** 
Dependency properties are mainly used in case of reusable controls such that the Dependency property is bound to some control’s property in the view. This could be bound to some CLR property in the ViewModel which in turn would update the view. Hence, the best thing is to bind it to a CLR property.